# iOS - Draw within boundary limit

Tags: ios, swift, drawing, uibezierpath, blending

I wanted to draw only close path, like inside the border.

I have done code below, A close path will be find from flood fill algorythm
 
**Below is close, i wanted draw only inside this close path**

```
if !closePath.isEmpty {
            closePath.close()
            let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
            context.setBlendMode(.copy)
            context.addPath(closePath.cgPath)
            context.setLineCap(.round)
            context.setAlpha(1.0)
            context.setLineWidth(1)
            context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
            context.strokePath()

        }
```

**While touch move**

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        drawFloodFill(path: UIBezierPath())
        // Drawing code
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() // get your current context
        context?.saveGState() // save the current state
        context?.setBlendMode(.sourceIn) // change blend mode to DestinationOut (R = D * (1-Sa))

        if touchEnd == true {
            UIColor.orange.set()
        } else {
            UIColor.yellow.set();
        }

        drawingPath.lineWidth = 10
        drawingPath.lineCapStyle = .round
        drawingPath.stroke()
        context?.restoreGState() // restore state of context
    }
```

I have used blend mode as Source In.

It is taking too much time to draw.